# How to transfer a question from one StackExchange site to another?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, migration

I had asked a [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3896/read-write-dev-ttysdio0-like-a-file-closed) in Android Enthusiasts which got closed as it was more relevant in StackExchange site.

Is there anyway to transfer that question without creating a new one?

Comment: Point of order: This--and each of the other Stack Exchange sites--is NOT a forum.

Comment: I'm sorry.. with due respect, can you please clarify...

Comment: A "forum" implies discussion. Discussion is discouraged here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flag it for moderator attention; the diamond mods have the ability to migrate from any site to any site.

Comment: I did flag that question for moderator, however the reply was:
  
No. You have to repost from scratch. You can open the question for edit to copy the source, however! – Michael Paulukonis♦

Comment: If Michael is right, then it would be great to see this feature added, as there is no point in creating the same question again. The ported old question can have additional meta data as which forum it came from, its comments, other statistics, etc.

Comment: @JeffAtwood: If that's so, then that's a new feature.

Comment: Well look at that. There it is in the "mod" menu. When did that go live?

Comment: Huh, I looked for that option for the specific question TheCottonSilk is referring to but couldn't find it.  It's a Christmas miracle!

Comment: It's on the mod menu, and the question can't have been already closed.

Comment: @Al: Thanks, that was the problem, the question was already closed.